# Unable to add resources to final jar for maven project in Intellij

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am unable to add images from my resources directory (which is marked as resources root) to the final jar that I want t generate. I have tried building a jar using File -> Project Structure -> Project Settings -> Artifacts -> Click green plus sign -> Jar -> From modules with dependencies. But failed. I have also tried building a jar from the Maven project window in Intellij. Which failed as well.

Here is my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.sample.project</groupId>
<artifactId>login</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>
                src/main/resources
            </directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.sample.project.Login</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

My project structure looks like this: [Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmVVy.jpg)

zip file of my sample project: 
[Archive](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ag4WLhBfyGCsaxzAUFZxDrHKi98)

Answer (score 0):

```
<build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <defaultGoal>dependency:sources</defaultGoal>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>

        </resources>
```

Above code in pom.xml would copy xml files located in resources. You can change to some other files or remove

```
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                </includes>
```

will copy all files in resources.

Comment: That still doesn't add the image file to the jar

Comment: try this https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html

Answer (score 0):

The files that you have in the directory `src/resources/` need to be moved to `src/main/resources/`, otherwise Maven will ignore them.

Additionally, remove this

```
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>
                src/main/resources
            </directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

because this is the default convention that Maven will use anyway.

Comment: I do not have a src/resources directory, my resources directory is src/main/resources