# Storing data in text files with Java/Maven

Tags: java, database, maven, properties, store

I wrote a little Java app for analyzing .csv files. Now I want to keep reading from and writing to a .txt file, which acts similar to a mini-database. For this purpose I simply added the .txt in my project and used the Files.readString(Path) and Files.write(Path path, byte[] bytes) methods.

When I do this in IntelliJ I have no problems but as soon as I build/export the file with Maven and started with the created launcher the app didn't work because the project structure / file organization isn't the same anymore.

I also tried to just add the .txt file to the exported folder afterwards but even then I couldn't manage to implement a relative path to the file.

I'm still relatively new to programming and it's just a small app so I don't think mySQL would fit my needs. I've also read that I could store the data in a property file but I don't know if that would be the right way to archive what I want. Certainly it must be possible to somehow keep a .txt for reading and writing in your exported project. Does someone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a ´*.txt` file for storing, that file cannot be *inside* the jar because the jar cannot change its contents while running.

You need to put the file somewhere else, either at some dedicated location (let the user choose/configure one), or next to the jar. To figure out your own execution path, you can use

[How to get the path of a running JAR file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/320542/927493)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I managed to fix it. I just put a folder in the same directory as the .jar file and then started the Paths from the directory containing the .jar. So I only had to use Path.of("resources/database.txt"). Turns out my problem was actually to put everything in a single, executable .jar file. I still have to start it with this command inside a .bat file though:

java --module-path javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml -jar csvTool1.2.jar

Do you know how I could implement that into the .jar somehow?

Answer (score -1):

Maven is one tricky tool. You need to go to the pom file and add the resource.
[Unable to add resources to final jar for maven project in Intellij](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49808337/unable-to-add-resources-to-final-jar-for-maven-project-in-intellij).

-I hope this helps
Trader